# Link Xamarin Application and Google Firestore using Google Cloud Firestore

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a Xamarin Application that I want to connect to my Firestore Database.
I used 'Plugin.GoogleFirestore' but it's too old and I can release my application with this package, so I downloaded 'Google.Cloud.Firebase' and 'Google.Cloud.Firebase.V1' packages. they work very well. I'm using them for my mobile application and my Windows application.
For my windows application they work correctly, but I have problem with my Xamarin mobile Application.

I can't connect application with database because system can't find json file.
This is the error:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Error reading credential file from location app-firebase-adminsdk.json: Could not find file "/app-firebase-adminsdk.json"
Please check the value of the Environment Variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS. ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file "/app-firebase-adminsdk.json"
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean anonymous, System.IO.FileOptions options) [0x001aa] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:239 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access, System.IO.FileShare share, System.Int32 bufferSize, System.Boolean isAsync, System.Boolean anonymous) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:149 
  at System.IO.FileStream..ctor (System.String path, System.IO.FileMode mode, System.IO.FileAccess access) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/jenkins/workspace/archive-mono/2020-02/android/release/mcs/class/corlib/System.IO/FileStream.cs:86 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.IO.FileStream..ctor(string,System.IO.FileMode,System.IO.FileAccess)
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.GetStream (System.String filePath) [0x00000] in C:\Apiary\2022-12-01.12-06-01\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:380 
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialFromFileAsync (System.String credentialPath, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) [0x0002f] in C:\Apiary\2022-12-01.12-06-01\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:162 
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.<CreateDefaultCredentialAsync>g__GetAdcFromEnvironmentVariableAsync|11_0 () [0x0005c] in C:\Apiary\2022-12-01.12-06-01\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:108 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.<CreateDefaultCredentialAsync>g__GetAdcFromEnvironmentVariableAsync|11_0 () [0x000b0] in C:\Apiary\2022-12-01.12-06-01\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:114 
  at Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.DefaultCredentialProvider.CreateDefaultCredentialAsync () [0x00037] in C:\Apiary\2022-12-01.12-06-01\Src\Support\Google.Apis.Auth\OAuth2\DefaultCredentialProvider.cs:85 
  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.DefaultChannelCredentialsCache.<.ctor>b__5_1 () [0x00027] in /_/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/DefaultChannelCredentialsCache.cs:51 
  at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.WaitWithUnwrappedExceptions (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00009] in /_/Google.Api.Gax/TaskExtensions.cs:51 
  at Google.Api.Gax.TaskExtensions.ResultWithUnwrappedExceptions[T] (System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[TResult] task) [0x00000] in /_/Google.Api.Gax/TaskExtensions.cs:30 
  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.DefaultChannelCredentialsCache.GetCredentials () [0x00000] in /_/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/DefaultChannelCredentialsCache.cs:67 
  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ChannelPool.GetChannel (Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcAdapter grpcAdapter, System.String endpoint, Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.GrpcChannelOptions channelOptions) [0x00018] in /_/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/ChannelPool.cs:74 
  at Google.Api.Gax.Grpc.ClientBuilderBase`1[TClient].CreateCallInvoker () [0x00034] in /_/Google.Api.Gax.Grpc/ClientBuilderBase.cs:366 
  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.BuildImpl () [0x00006] in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1/Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1/FirestoreClient.g.cs:414 
  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClientBuilder.Build () [0x00001] in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1/Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1/FirestoreClient.g.cs:400 
  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDbBuilder.Build () [0x00056] in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/FirestoreDbBuilder.cs:105 
  at Google.Cloud.Firestore.FirestoreDb.Create (System.String projectId, Google.Cloud.Firestore.V1.FirestoreClient client) [0x00000] in /_/apis/Google.Cloud.Firestore/Google.Cloud.Firestore/FirestoreDb.cs:104
```

And this is my code:

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"app-firebase-adminsdk.json";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS", path);
FirestoreDb databaseFS = FirestoreDb.Create("appmobile");
```

I also tried

```
string path = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, @"app-firebase-adminsdk.json")
```

instead of

```
string path = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"app-firebase-adminsdk.json";
```

but it doesn't works..

.json file is installed in my app project with:

- Build Action: Embedded resource
- Copy to Output Directory: Do not copy

In Xamarin.Android and Xamarin.iOS as:

- Build Action: Content
- Copy to Output Directory: Copy Always

Do you have any idea?

Comment: try using the filename without the path, or with just a relative "./" path

Comment: not works, same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may set the wrong `Build Action` for the .json file.

For Android:

- Add any file into the Assets folder in the Android project and mark
  the Build Action as AndroidAsset to use it with
  OpenAppPackageFileAsync.

For ios:

- Add any file into the Resources folder in the iOS project and mark
  the Build Action as BundledResource to use it with
  OpenAppPackageFileAsync.